# Flutter button, unwanted extra top and bottom padding

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to customize a Flutter button:

```
ButtonTheme(
    child: FlatButton(
        child: Text(_text),
        color: _color,
        onPressed: _onPressed,
    ),
    minWidth: 40,
),
```

But I can't get rid of the extra top and bottom padding:

[image: Extra padding]

`FlatButton`, `RaisedButton`, `MaterialButton`, all of them have the padding.

NOTE: I have more customizations, such as padding, text trimming, and border-radius.

Comment: Where do you put the button (the parent widget)? Have you tried `Expanded` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To remove that padding  add - `materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,`

```
ButtonTheme(
                            child: FlatButton(
                              materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,  // add this
                              child: Text('Dummy'),
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              onPressed: () {},
                            ),
                            minWidth: 40,
                          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Set padding to 0 for your `ButtonTheme` like shown below

```
    new ButtonTheme(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      child: FlatButton(
        child: Text(_text),
        color: _color,
        onPressed: _onPressed,
        ),
      minWidth: 40,
    ),
```