# How to reduce size of raisedButton in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

I want to reduce the size of raisedbutton. By default it is 88*36. I want smaller buttons on screen. 
The outcome is like above:

Code for each button is like below:

```
ButtonTheme(
            minWidth: 20,
            height: 22,
            child: RaisedButton(
              textColor: Colors.black87,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text(
                "31",
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          )
```

But, what is happening is, even though i am able to see button of size 20*22, button is getting clicked even when I click around the button. (In the space between two buttons)

Am I doing it the correct way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter button, unwanted extra top and bottom padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54938971/flutter-button-unwanted-extra-top-and-bottom-padding)

Comment: Thanks. This worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

It should work with `ButtonTheme` but you can wrap with parent widget like `SizedBox` to match to parent size:

```
SizedBox(
  width: 60,
  child: RaisedButton(
      textColor: Colors.black87,
      //..
  ),
)
```

Using `ButtonTheme`:

```
ButtonTheme(
  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
  minWidth: 60,
  child: RaisedButton(
      textColor: Colors.black87,
      //..
  ),
),
```